# Using variable for WebKitFormBoundary makes request invalid

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following python code that posts a request successfully

```
import requests

cookies = {'BNES_JSESSIONID': 'R2aVMfNrT78PyhSgyqW6Kj7BlBMOR7cQqB+Tq7wGQl34xSno1KKqpymu/ZLhny2lshfxmOnZiFy8Zbvw+vcSPCPOAALQXhOdFcYX61dU7WDszMVLkwHKehvnHfmubbwQG5BhwWAjqWJlKz22mi985kyPwyYEwx8y'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryB6r6VIYgOSHWqj5I'}
data = '------WebKitFormBoundaryB6r6VIYgOSHWqj5I\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="selectAser"\r\n\r\n211053300\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryB6r6VIYgOSHWqj5I\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="phoneNo"\r\n\r\n55075052\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryB6r6VIYgOSHWqj5I\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="selectAsed"\r\n\r\n120987470-1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryB6r6VIYgOSHWqj5I\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="comReg"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryB6r6VIYgOSHWqj5I\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="bankType"\r\n\r\n1850\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryB6r6VIYgOSHWqj5I\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryB6r6VIYgOSHWqj5I\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="searchType"\r\n\r\n0745\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryB6r6VIYgOSHWqj5I--\r\n'

response = requests.post('https://eservices.gov./', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

I tried to make it simpler so I have used variable for the value like that

```
import requests

def post_with_custom_boundary(c_boundary):
    url = 'https://eservices.gov./'
    cookies = {'BNES_JSESSIONID': 'FBVxGgtjjJhDGmcnG/XOglUeuJlG/mwpJH9+ICQw/bL3/2Y383HWR4f+WzRXsJBG5jHf33qCsgMBOHLeTKxJRBwlkrkKE1tGbdywVgdikWhC4VcCUd1yIIYJBFm4m/60lfkGqvgk+UfaMbPKe3CUVRvsTaMCLn+A'}
    headers = {'Content-Type': f'multipart/form-data; boundary={c_boundary}'}

    data = f'{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="selectAser"\r\n\r\n211053300\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="phoneNo"\r\n\r\n55075052\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="selectAsed"\r\n\r\n120987470-1\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="comReg"\r\n\r\n\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="bankType"\r\n\r\n1850\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="searchType"\r\n\r\n0745\r\n{c_boundary}--\r\n'

    response = requests.post(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(response.text)

c_boundary = '------WebKitFormBoundaryg3LDfuaso7lfkkvj'
post_with_custom_boundary(c_boundary)
```

That is too weird. Any ideas how to fix that problem?

Note that the first code is working well and returns this valid response
`تم تسجيل الطلب بنجاح`
which means `Registered Successfully`

Comment: Show us the response you get from the second code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you should use the `c_boundary` variable only in the headers and not repeat it for each form field in the data.

Try this code:

```
import requests

def post_with_custom_boundary(c_boundary):
    url = 'https://eservices.gov/'
    cookies = {'BNES_JSESSIONID':'FBVxGgtjjJhDGmcnG/XOglUeuJlG/mwpJH9+ICQw/bL3/2Y383HWR4f+WzRXsJBG5jHf33qCsgMBOHLeTKxJRBwlkrkKE1tGbdywVgdikWhC4VcCUd1yIIYJBFm4m/60lfkGqvgk+UfaMbPKe3CUVRvsTaMCLn+A'}
    headers = {'Content-Type': f'multipart/form-data; boundary={c_boundary}'}

    data = f'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selectAser"\r\n\r\n211053300\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="phoneNo"\r\n\r\n55075052\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="selectAsed"\r\n\r\n120987470-1\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="comReg"\r\n\r\n\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="bankType"\r\n\r\n1850\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="searchType"\r\n\r\n0745\r\n{c_boundary}--\r\n'

    response = requests.post(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(response.text)

c_boundary = '------WebKitFormBoundaryg3LDfuaso7lfkkvj'
post_with_custom_boundary(c_boundary)
```

I hope the request should be valid.

Comment: this returns something went wrong in response `` <h1 style="text-align:center;">حدث خطأ ما </h1>``. Note that the first code is working well, you can try it.

Comment: so do you mean that the code is working fine know ?

Comment: Nom it doesn't work. The first code I changed again as the cookie is temporary. Note that the first code is working well but I need to use variable for the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it using such a code

```
import requests
import random
import string

def generate_boundary():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=16))

def post_with_custom_boundary(c_aser, c_phone, c_ased, c_bank, c_search):
    c_boundary = generate_boundary()
    cookies = {'BNES_JSESSIONID': 'R2aVMfNrT78PyhSgyqW6Kj7BlBMOR7cQqB+Tq7wGQl34xSno1KKqpymu/ZLhny2lshfxmOnZiFy8Zbvw+vcSPCPOAALQXhOdFcYX61dU7WDszMVLkwHKehvnHfmubbwQG5BhwWAjqWJlKz22mi985kyPwyYEwx8y'}
    headers = {'Content-Type': f'multipart/form-data; boundary={c_boundary}'}
    data = (
        f'--{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="selectAser"\r\n\r\n{c_aser}\r\n'
        f'--{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="phoneNo"\r\n\r\n{c_phone}\r\n'
        f'--{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="selectAsed"\r\n\r\n{c_ased}\r\n'
        f'--{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="comReg"\r\n\r\n\r\n'
        f'--{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="bankType"\r\n\r\n{c_bank}\r\n'
        f'--{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n'
        f'--{c_boundary}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="searchType"\r\n\r\n{c_search}\r\n'
        f'--{c_boundary}--\r\n'
    )
    response = requests.post('https://eservice.gov/execFileUpload2', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(response.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = {
        'c_aser': '211053300',
        'c_phone': '55075052',
        'c_ased': '120987470-1',
        'c_bank': '1850',
        'c_search': '0745'
    }
    post_with_custom_boundary(**params)
```